# Angular 6 Application Productions build gets successfully but on load throws error No component factory found for t

Tags: angular, angular6, production-environment

I am building a application where when i run the below command it gets generated successfully & also dist folder is created.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /ICS/
```

But when i run the application it shows me the login screen as well but when I log in i throws the below error.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for t. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for t. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

I cannot understand what it this "t" coming from ?

Comment: can you post your root module code as well?

Comment: do you have any entry components which means components called inside other components ? like using component for pop up or something like that ?

Comment: yes i have dailog box which opens & i have added this to my entry component in login component should i add that to my app module's entry component ?

Comment: then you need to add entry components property in the parent module @JigneshMistry

Comment: if you are using lazy loading modules then you add it to the parent lazy loaded module, else add it to app module

Comment: ok i will move that form login module to app module

Comment: Done still same error my app works well in ng build when i add the --prod flag it throws error Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have some components injected or used in other components so if you are using lazy loading modules then you need to add it to entrycomponents array in the parent lazy loaded module, if not then you need to add it to app module.

also make sure that all entry components added to declaration array.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YourComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [YourComponent]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

if your entry component in another module, you should export it there first to use it.

```
exports: [ YourComponent ]
```

> **that issue happens alot specially when you use components as popups or dialogs**

Comment: Done still same error my app works well in ng build when i add the --prod flag it throws error Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for t.

Comment: Sure i will just check out

Comment: make sure that all entry components also in declaration array